# Problem while querying a javascript view couchdb?

Tags: javascript, python, view, couchdb

I am trying to query a couchdb jacscript view but when I request it ( with get python requests) it returns me nothing whereas there a keys associated to the values I want (on the database).
Here is my python code :

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.age, {password:doc.password, gender: doc.gender})
}
```

python code :

```
>>> res = requests.get('http://admin:kolea21342@localhost:5984/reviewin_users/_design/design_users/_view/id?key="17"')
>>> print(res.text)
```

output :

```
{"total_rows":15,"offset":15,"rows":[

]}
```

Thanks to everyone who will respond !

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that age is a number in your document and when you are querying it you are passing 17 as a string ("17") and therefore it is finding no matches?

So that your code could instead be:

```
res = requests.get('http://admin:kolea21342@localhost:5984/reviewin_users/_design/design_users/_view/id?key=17')
```